# How can I place one VideoView below another VideoView in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-videoview

i need to create a video view which should lie just beneath the one with id "video1" at run time.
The code works fine for creating the view, but I am not able to place it below the videoView with id "video1". Here is the code:

```
            RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
            layout.getLayoutParams();
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.video1);
            videoView2 = new VideoView(jazz.this);
            videoView2.setLayoutParams(params);
            videoView2.setLayoutParams(new 
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200));
            layout.addView(videoView2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code:

```
 videoView2.setLayoutParams(params);
        videoView2.setLayoutParams(new 
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200))
```

You set the LayoutParams twice...

Use this:

```
 VideoView v = new VideoView(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.video1);
    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
  container.addView(v);
```

It will be work. hople to help you

Comment: What should I do? I need to set parameters of the videoview and also place it below the other videoview.

Comment: And then. If have more than one VideoView in a same container.It will be work with something wrong. take it in google out of china or baidu in china if it happened

Answer (score 1):

You should set params for you video2 like this :

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
        videoView2 = new VideoView(this);
        videoView2.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,200));
        layout.addView(videoView2);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) videoView2.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.video1);
        videoView2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

And your video1 should have a height param set , because the videoview measurement is based on the video you set , by the looks of it , no video path is been defined , so if video1 height=wrap_content , it takes the entire screen , there is no bound . I have mine in the xml like this :

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```